# How to receive native messages from chrome extension to Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which gets the location URL and I want it to send that URL to a Mac app.

I was able to run [this demo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), but I don't know how I can receive the message in a Mac app. Where would get I the message?

Comment: The Mac app would have to be written to listen for the message on ```stdin``` i.e. the standard input.  Not familiar with objective-c, so no idea how to do it more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can use.

1. **Native Messaging API.** This does have the limitation that Chrome must launch the process and communicate to it through stdio,
   conforming to native message API protocols .
2. Your native app can expose a web server on a local port. The
   extension can then try to connect to this port and talk to your app.

I would suggest the first solution as its a pretty secure soultion.